# Package.json not found error when updating using npm-check-updates

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I'm trying to update my node packages/modules and a lot of people (many from StackOverflow) recommended 'npm-check-updates' so I downloaded via npm and ran it. It gave me this error and I'm not sure what's wrong. Is something wrong with my PATH variable in system settings or something? I can't seem to find anything useful with searching Google. Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npm-check-updates` node module requires package.json file to check for the versions that your application is currently using. From the code, it looks for particularly `package.json` in the current directory to read application dependencies and throws an error if the file is not found.

[Github Source Code](https://github.com/tjunnone/npm-check-updates/blob/48a9487ed47d0038ad65844923bb121c3ff7ca7b/lib/npm-check-updates.js#L185)

If `package.json` file exists, the module checks which packages can be updated to a higher version and are outdated. Once you review the suggestions and manually verifiy, you would want to run the module with `-u` option, which will automatically upgrade the `package.json` file with the newer version numbers of the dependencies. Once this is done, you can run `npm install` to download the latest versions.

Here is an example of running this update.

```
~/Downloads/hackingedu/project 512-> ./node_modules/npm-check-updates/bin/npm-check-updates 

"babelify" can be updated from 6.0.2 to 6.1.2 (Installed: 6.0.2, Latest: 6.1.2)
"browserify" can be updated from 9.0.8 to 10.2.4 (Installed: 9.0.8, Latest: 10.2.4)
"canvas" can be updated from 1.2.2 to 1.2.3 (Installed: none, Latest: 1.2.3)
"express" can be updated from 4.12.3 to 4.12.4 (Installed: 4.12.3, Latest: 4.12.4)

Run with '-u' to upgrade your package.json
~/Downloads/hackingedu/project 513-> mv package.json package.json.old
~/Downloads/hackingedu/project 514-> ./node_modules/npm-check-updates/bin/npm-check-updates 
package.json not found
~/Downloads/hackingedu/project 515-> mv package.json.old package.json
~/Downloads/hackingedu/project 516-> cat package.json 
{
  "name": "workshop",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "babelify": "6.0.2",
    "browserify": "9.0.8",
    "canvas": "1.2.2",
    "express": "4.12.3",
    "gameboy": "0.2.0",
    "socket.io": "1.3.5"
  }
}
~/Downloads/hackingedu/project 517-> ./node_modules/npm-check-updates/bin/npm-check-updates -u

"babelify" can be updated from 6.0.2 to 6.1.2 (Installed: 6.0.2, Latest: 6.1.2)
"browserify" can be updated from 9.0.8 to 10.2.4 (Installed: 9.0.8, Latest: 10.2.4)
"canvas" can be updated from 1.2.2 to 1.2.3 (Installed: none, Latest: 1.2.3)
"express" can be updated from 4.12.3 to 4.12.4 (Installed: 4.12.3, Latest: 4.12.4)

package.json upgraded
~/Downloads/hackingedu/project 518-> cat package.json 
{
  "name": "workshop",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "babelify": "6.1.2",
    "browserify": "10.2.4",
    "canvas": "1.2.3",
    "express": "4.12.4",
    "gameboy": "0.2.0",
    "socket.io": "1.3.5"
  }
}
```

It is recommended to use semantic versioning in your `package.json` file, you can [learn more](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/package-dependencies-done-right/) on `package.json` best practices.